# Ordering by JSON

Tags: php, json

We are importing our JSON from an API. The JSON is pulling through fine but unordered

We want to order the JSON file by the name field, We have used uasort but it does not seem to take effect?

```
 $url="https://dev-api.ourwebsite.com";
 $ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);



// DUMPING THE JSON
$json=json_decode($result, true);


uasort($json, 'name');  



foreach($json as $value) {


$course_name=$value["name"];


}
```

Comment: pick one of the [array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). (usort might be best for this)

Comment: hI Jeff, thanks, we did try uasort but it does not seem to make a difference to the results

Comment: 'name' is not a function/callable (at least not shown here), so it can't have an effect. Here's [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) for how to use uasort.

Answer (score 1):

[usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) (or [uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) if you need to keep the keys of the array) is what you need:

```
<?php
// mocking some data
$json = [
    ["name" => "paul"],
    ["name" => "jeff"],
    ["name" => "anna"]

];

uasort($json, 
      // this callable needs to return 1 or -1, depending on how you want it to sort
      function($a, $b) {
        if($a['name']>$b['name']) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }

     });

var_dump($json);

foreach($json as $value) {
    $course_name=$value["name"];
    echo $course_name."<br>";
}
// output:
array(3) {
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "anna"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "jeff"
  }
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "paul"
  }
}
anna
jeff
paul
```